# JHipster generated file failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'

Tags: java, angular, typescript, jhipster

I have generated the files by using JHipster and currently I am trying to call a query which involves a Date variable but am getting a failed conversion.

The following is my typescript file method which provide the criteria query for the search.

```
  loadSearchPage(page?: number): void {
    const pageToLoad: number = page || this.page;

    this.transactionService
      .query({
        page: pageToLoad - 1,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        sort: this.sort(),
        'transStartDate.equals': new Date()
      })
      .subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<ITransaction[]>) => this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers, pageToLoad),
        () => this.onError()
      );
  }
```

It then calls for the query method within the transaction.

```
  query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http
      .get<ITransaction[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(map((res: EntityArrayResponseType) => this.convertDateArrayFromServer(res)));
  }
```

The following is the default JHipster convertDateArrayFromServer method that was provided.

```
  protected convertDateArrayFromServer(res: EntityArrayResponseType): EntityArrayResponseType {
    if (res.body) {
      res.body.forEach((transaction: ITransaction) => {
        transaction.transStartDate = transaction.transStartDate ? moment(transaction.transStartDate) : undefined;
        transaction.transEndDate = transaction.transEndDate ? moment(transaction.transEndDate) : undefined;
      });
    }
        return res;   
  }
```

I have tried researching on methods to work around it and also tried out the following however the request level file that was generated from JHipster had a very different structure and I wasn't able to modify it accordingly to this webpage: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters

Would kindly seek an assistance for a workable solution to the following error that was thrown.

> "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
> required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property
> 'transStartDate.equals'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
> convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for
> value 'Fri Dec 03 2021 09:22:35 GMT 0800 (Singapore Standard Time)';
> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt
> failed for value [Fri Dec 03 2021 09:22:35 GMT 0800 (Singapore
> Standard Time)]

Answer (score 0):

The backend does not understand the JavaScript date string you are passing, the easiest solution is to use JHipster's date/time library of choice ([dayjs](https://day.js.org/) or [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) in older versions).

```js
import * as moment from 'moment';
// ...
        'transStartDate.equals': moment()
// ...
```

Or:

```js
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';
// ...
        'transStartDate.equals': dayjs()
// ...
```

This should in theory return all the `Transaction` that have a `transStartDate` equal to the current date.